# Bootstrap navbar menu bar does not appear

Tags: javascript, c#, razor, navbar

I made a menu bar using bootstrarp navbar and it was working fine but suddenly it no longer loads. Only one button appears as shown in the images.

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Menu</span>

                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Estimaci&#243;nApp</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="/">Inicio</a></li>

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Estimación<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href='/EstimacionVaradas'>Estimar Varada de Embarcaciones</a></li>
                            <li><a href='/AjustarPronosticos'>Ajustar Estimaciones</a></li>
                            <li><a href='/'>Comparar Estimaciones </a></li>
                            <li><a href='/'>Consultar Estimación de Varadas</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Negociación<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href='/RentabilidadPresupuestos'>Proyectar rentabilidad de trabajos</a></li>
                            <li><a href='/'>Comparar proyecciones</a></li>
                            <li><a href='/OrdenPedidos'>Verificar presupuestos concretados</a></li>
                            <li><a href='/'>Consultar rentabilidad de trabajos</a></li>
                            <li><a href='/'>Consultar rentabilidad no concretados</a></li>
                            <li><a href='/'>Consultar trabajos comunes</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Planificación<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href='/CalendarioVaradas'>Determinar orden de varada</a></li>
                            <li><a href='/InventarioInsumos'>Determinar inventario de insumos</a></li>
                            <li><a href='/ServicioTerceros'>Determinar servicios tercerizados</a></li>
                            <li><a href='/'>Consultar orden de Varadas</a></li>
                            <li><a href='/'>Consultar servicios tercerizados</a></li>
                            <li><a href='/'>Consultar servicios tercerizados</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li><a href="/Home/About">Acerca de</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/Contact">Contacto</a></li>
                </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="/Account/Register" id="registerLink">Registrarse</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Account/Login" id="loginLink">Iniciar sesi&#243;n</a></li>
</ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What's going on?

Comment: Your code is working: https://jsfiddle.net/8u23qfox/

Comment: Most likely the bootstrap css is not loading